# Why does "read" behave differently with the same input?

Tags: bash, built-in

Why does [read](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) behave differently with the same input from a pipe and a heredoc:

```
printf "" | while read line; do echo "line=$line"; done   # outputs nothing    
while read line; do echo "line=$line"; done <<< ""        # outputs 'line='
```

How can I disable output in the second case?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the `<<<` operator, what does that do?

Comment: If you use 'echo' or 'printf "\n"' instead of printf, the first statement results in same result at the second.

Comment: It's a "here string", as it were.  A string which is processed as a here document.

Comment: This is one of those cases where I learned as much from the question as I did from the answer.  Never used a "here doc" before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `$'\c'`:

```
man bash | less -p '\\c * suppress trailing newline'

str=""
while read line; do echo "line=$line"; done <<<$'\c'"${str}"

str="abc"
while read line; do echo "line=$line"; done <<<$'\c'"${str}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The here document has an implicit newline (`\n`) at the end; `printf ""` outputs nothing whatsoever.  I don't know offhand of a way to get rid of the implicit newline.

Answer (score 2):

If you can discard all empty lines...

```
while read line; do if test -n "$line"; then echo "line=$line"; fi; done <<< ""
```